# <a href link doesn't open when clicked on. it only works if I right click and then open in new tab

Tags: hyperlink

So I'm still learning, and I can't figure out why my links won't work. If I click "open in new tab", it does work. I'm trying to link to another external page.
I've read that this could be due to another linked js file... but what js code could effect links like this?

I mean if I'm going to go through all my other files I'd rather know what I'm looking for.

Here is my link: 
visit

FYI, no links work for external URLs, but it works when I use links to navigate around my own website.

Comment: Please show your HTML code.

Comment: I figured it out. In an linked js file I had: 
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

Comment: fixed a typo and a capitalization

Answer (score 0):

check you achor link. That is lacking of closing tag `</a>`